# iOS, SOAP Parsing ?null data

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, soap, nsarray

I'm going to use SOAP web service in iPhone project, I'm starting a connections and then parsing the data received using the XML Parser. When I parse I use three functions:

First Function :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;
```

Second Function :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;
```

Third Function :

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;
```

The problem is when I parse I am searching for three attributes:

1. Name,
2. ID,
3. Image

after parsing I found that the size (count) of the Image array is bigger than the ID and after when I started printing the array, I found that the image array is containing null objects which is not found in the web service, I tried to remove it from the array but I failed.

Are there any recommendations for the solution?

Comment: it is difficult to tell the problem without seen the code inside methods

Comment: Also post XML response which you are describing.

Comment: -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
        if(recordFoundImgs){
                [Base64 initialize];
                NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] init];
                if ((string == NULL) || ([string length] % 4 != 0)) {
                    data = nil;
                    return;
                } else {
                        data = [Base64 decode:string];
                }
                [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
        }
    }
}

Comment: @MostafaA.Khattab don't paste your code in comment instead of edit your question again.